# How to launch new Firefox window with multiple tabs using Python

Tags: python, windows, firefox, tabs

I want to create a MSWindows Python program that would launch a new Firefox window with multiple tabs each time it is run. For example if I want to search "hello", a new window pops out (even if a Firefox window is already open) and then launches a Google and Bing tabs searching for "hello". If I change the keyword to "world", a new browser pops out again with Google and Bing tabs searching for "world".

I've looked at the webbrowser module but couldn't get it to:
1. Launch a new browser when a browser is already open: e.g. webbrowser.open('http://www.google.com',new=1) will instead open a new tab
2. Launch multiple tabs simultaneously in the same window

Appreciate the help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`webbrowser` just doesn't give you this degree of control.  Use `subprocess` instead, to explicitly launch firefox with a new window and then add tabs to it.  The firefox command line arguments reference is [here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments#List_of_command_line_arguments_.28incomplete.29), but, briefly, what you want is one `firefox.exe -new-window <url>` (using the URL you want in lieu of `<url>` of course), then one or more `firefox.exe -new-tab <url>` (ditto).  You may also want to control width and height, use a different profile from the default one, etc -- the command-line arguments let you do all that.

Comment: @newbie, on SO, "thanks are silver, accepts are gold" -- if my answer has solved your problem, why not accept it (using the checkmark-shaped icon under the number of votes you can see at the left of the answer)?-)

Comment: To search using your default search engine for a piece of text you can  use firefox.exe -search "your search text" This will open a new window with the result of the search.

Answer (score 6):

In python 3.6, a complete answer will include both webbrowser.open_new() and webbrowser.open_new_tab() from the [webbrowser docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/webbrowser.html).

```
import webbrowser

def main():
    # print(webbrowser._browsers) # for Python 3.x to determine .get() arg
    browser = webbrowser.get('firefox')

    urls = ['url1', 'url2', 'url3']

    first = True
    for url in urls:
        if first:
            browser.open_new(url)
            first = False
        else:
            browser.open_new_tab(url)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Enjoy the code. +1 if it helped you out. Cheers!